# помощь в создании смс оповещение

Tags: веб-программирование

Привет всем... у меня вопрос такой, я новенький в сфере программирования, интересует, с чего начать если хочу смс-оповещание на своем сайте...  я знаю о платных ресурсах, встречал в сети пару тройку сайтов компаний  которые предоставляют данную услугу, но если кто-то это сделал, то и я смогу, мой профиль это html, css и js..  так вот вопрос конкретный, могу ли я это сделать без операторов связи или мне нужна и их помощь и доступ (при условии, что я имею свою базу тел номеров, и оповещение только для клиентов моего сайта), просьба откликнуться всем, кто в этом знает толк...  какой язык программирования нужно знать?

Comment: Ответьте для себя вот на какой вопрос: может ли сервер, **не подключенный к интернету**, но знающий IP-адреса пользователей, предоставлять этим пользователям доступ к размещённому на нём сайту?

Comment: либо подключайте gsm-модем и шлите через него либо выбирайте любого агрегатора, вот того самого, платного и шлите через него. Любой сотовый оператор за передачу SMS берет деньги, так что какой бы способ вы не выбрали все равно будет платно. А язык любой какой нравится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начало мои короткие суждения. Хочу отметить, что это сугубо мое личное мнение и тому нет прямых доказательств, а только косвенные "улики", простите за каламбур, это уже оттенки юр. образования... Или я не умею пользоваться поисковым сайтами или же эта информация нарочно скрывается от лиц не приближенных...  Поисковики сразу, выдают информацию на сайты, которые предлагают платные услуги по данному сервису.  Можно подумать, что я плохо искал, но не нашел ни какой информации, просто люди добрые полсказали....

Если кого-то заинтересует, то все оказалось на много проще, чем казалось. Для того, что бы данный сервис подключить к своему сайту, надо просто позвонить любому сотовому оператору связи в своем городе и сказать, что вам надо. Вас свяжут с отделом продаж данной услуги. Дальше получайте инструкции от представителя сотового оператора, что и как надо делать. Надо отметить тот важный факт, что подписать договор как физическое лицо не получиться, договор на данную услуги оператор связи подписывает только с частными (индивидуальными) предпринимателями, с компаниями "ООО" или "АО"... Далее, не скажу обо всех, у меня информация о операторе BeeLine. Данная услуга стоит... Приведу скрины с ценами.

[[image: цены[1]] [image: цены]

И еще надо сказать, что все это дело пишется на PHP